# The connection string 'MyConnection' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute."

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, connection-string

I use `Entity Framework Code First`,

My connection string is in a configuration file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=PC-X;Initial Catalog=MYdb;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

When I try to access the data (something that should create the DB) is falling with the following error:

> The connection string 'ApplicationServices' in the application's
>   configuration file does not contain the required providerName
>   attribute."

What am I missing?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

You're missing the following piece of code after the `connectionString` attribute (assuming that you're using SQL):

`providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`

Comment: If using Entity Framework: `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"`

Comment: I was trying to add this to the connection string.  Rather it is a new attribute to the <add /> element.  A sibling attribute to the connectionString attribute.

Comment: @IronMan84 i got type cast error after using SqlClient and EntityClient worked

Answer (score 16):

Sometime in the future. the complete code

```
<add name="YouContext" connectionString="Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName;Data Source=YourPCName;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Go down in your web.config until you reach the `providers` tag. 
For instance, here's my providers statement:

```
<providers><provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" ... /></providers>
```

you should add this `System.Data.SqlClient` as a provider name in your connection string
so your connection string should look like this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
 <add name="ApplicationServices" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=PC-X;Initial Catalog=MYdb;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning this is in the web.config, as someone using a product with dozens of different config files

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with an incorrect StartUp project target. In the PM console the target migration assembly project was correct.

I have a multiproject solution and the target was on some web-service project.

So I changed the StartUp to the main WebSite project and the migration have complited without errors.